Reduce type name in Lean
In Lean 4, the command
#reduce [1, 2, 3].length

shows 3 in the infoview. But the command
#reduce Fin [1, 2, 3].length

does not show Fin 3 (it shows Fin [1, 2, 3].length).
Is there a way to make it show Fin 3?
EDIT (to answer Jason Rute's question in the comments).
What I want is, if I introduce the type
def Vec (n : Nat) : Type := Fin n → Int

and the dependent function
def vec (L : List Int) : Vec L.length := fun i ↦ L.get i

to have the type of vec [1, 2, 3] show as Vec 3.
#check vec [1, 2, 3]  -- vec [1, 2, 3] : Vec [1, 2, 3].length

But I guess things like may have undergone some changes recently, because the following example behaves differently in Lean v4.9.1 and v4.12.0-rc1. Namely, if we consider the function
def type : {X : Type} → X → Type := fun {X} _  => X

then in Lean v4.9.1, we have
#reduce type 2     -- Nat
#reduce type (-2)  -- Int

and in Lean v4.12.0-rc1, we have
#reduce type 2     -- type 2
#reduce type (-2)  -- type (-2)


This might be an XY problem.  Why do you want this?

Note, you say you want the type of vec [1, 2, 3] to reduce to Vec 3, but it should fully reduce to Fin 3 -> Int actually.  If instead Vec was a structure or inductive type, then Vec 3 would be the terminal reduction.

Indeed! And with the current approach, with #reduce (types := true) Vec [1, 2, 3].length I get Fin [1, 2, 3].length → Rat, which does not reduce further.

In Lean 4.10 the #reduce command changed to speed it up.  It no longer reduces proofs and types by default.  You can still reduce types with (types := true).
#reduce Fin [1, 2, 3].length                  -- Fin [1, 2, 3].length
#reduce (types := true) Fin [1, 2, 3].length  -- Fin 3

Similarly:

use (proofs := true) for reducing proofs
use (proofs := true) (types := true) (in that order) for reducing both at the same time.

You can also find this information in the editor tooltip for #reduce.
